# Counting individual iterations in a nested loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, cell, nested-loops, cells

I have the following problem. I have initialized a variable that contains 20 cells, each cell will contain a matrix. Generation of my matrix is done via nested for loop so, I have:

```
matrices = cell(1,20);       

for 1:4
    for 1:5

       *do stuff to get matrix* 

   end
end
```

I want to be able to save the nth result in my cell...so for example

for outer loop 1, inner loop 1 ---> 1st element of cell

for outer loop 1, inner loop 2 ---> 2nd element of cell

etc, etc.

I know this would involve incorporating a

```
 matrices{counter} = result;
```

Somewhere in my loop, but I don't know where to include it and how to initiate the counter. I can't have a

```
for 1:20
```

at the beginning of my loop, because it would do the same task 20 different times and not save the proper result.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a `counter` outside of the outer loop or you can calculate the `current_index` at each iteration:

```
matrices = cell(1,20);  
counter = 1;
for k=1:4
    for j=1:5

       matrices{counter} = zeros(k,j);

       disp(counter);
       counter = counter+1;

       current_index = (k-1)*5+j;
       disp(current_index);

   end
end
```

Comment: If you define the lengths of `k` and `j` outside the loop, you could use [`sub2ind`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to elegantly get the index.